# MySQL query giving error You can't specify target table

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have this query.

```
UPDATE messages 
SET seen_by = CONCAT( seen_by, '3,')
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM messages WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET(3, seen_by) AND chat_id = 350)
```

But when I try to execute it, it gives me this error

> You can't specify target table 'messages' for update in FROM clause

I want to update the same table what I have used in my WHERE clause. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need a subquery.

Just replace `WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM messages WHERE xyz)` by `WHERE xyz`.

This is more straight forward and doesn't have to first load all IDs into RAM (if it would even have allowed you).

Comment: That helped. Thankyou very much. I thought it was only possible via subquery.